# django filter by field

Tags: django, filter, model, django-queryset

i searched but not find the answer, maybe i cant formulate question proper anyway please help me with this

i want to filter by not hard coded values , but by joined fields of each row

Example:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user1_id")
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user2_id")
    blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    blocked_user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    us1_del = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    us2_del = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())


class ConversationReply(models.Model):
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.TextField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to filter where each reply date gt than  conversation delete time.How to do this?

```
ConversationReply.objects.filter(datetime__gt= conversation__us1_del )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) for this:

```
from django.db.models import F
ConversationReply.objects.annotate(conv=F(conversation__us1_del)).filter(datetime__gt=conv)
```